# Generate array from another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

is there any way to transform this array

```
$old = array('white', 'blue', 'black');
```

into

```
$new = array( "white" => "white", "blue" => "blue", "black" => "black");
```

This is an example, but I have a large list of items and writing them is painful.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Try this: `foreach ($old as $value)
{
    $new[$value] = $value;
}`

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the values as both key/value and not just leave them as value only?

Answer (score 2):

```
$new = array_combine($old, $old);
```

Comment: `array_combine`, nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that my  answer also works, it think the best option is using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) as answered by [dont-panic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734189/dont-panic)

```
    $old = array('white', 'blue', 'black');
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($old as $value){
        $newArray["$value"] = $value;
    }

    var_dump($newArray);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["white"]=>
  string(5) "white"
  ["blue"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  ["black"]=>
  string(5) "black"
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/u9Uh5K)